# Adding Free SSL certificate to my website

Tags: php, ssl

I got a SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt using certbot client. Want to add this certificate to make my local website secure https.

I am hosting the website on a apache(xampp) server locally. I have created SSL certificate using certbot and added the certificate to vhosts conf file

**my httpd_vhosts.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost <domain name>:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
    ServerName <domain name>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/fullchain.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/privkey.pem"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/dashboard">
        Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I open the website the domain is still unsecure, am I missing something, can anyone please help?

I am seeing following error :
Your PC doesn’t trust this website’s security certificate.
The website’s security certificate is not yet valid or has expired.
The hostname in the website’s security certificate differs from the website you are trying to visit.
Error Code: DLG_FLAGS_INVALID_CA
DLG_FLAGS_SEC_CERT_DATE_INVALID
DLG_FLAGS_SEC_CERT_CN_INVALID

Comment: try to open the website by adding https:// instead of http:// in the url. If you get the secure version of the site you just need to add the rule to rewrite the request for port 80 to port 443 (ssl). If this test fails you have not configured properly the site

Comment: I have used 443 port but still it says the site is not secure, can you point me anyother resource or issues that I can look at

Comment: Potential issue could be the cert path - try using the full path name

Comment: you don't have to use port 443. you have to use https:// instead of http:// in the url

Comment: It is finding the cert, no issue with the path, because if i remove the cert the server doesnt start up

Comment: "hostname in the website’s security certificate differs from the website" is the clue.  The certificate has ended up with a different name. Could be as simple as one having www. the other not.  You can view the certificate details via the browser